# JQuery localscroll slow movement

Tags: jquery, scroll, lazy-loading

I am building a scrolling website using JQuery localscroll, building on a few demo's I have seen, I have built this site so far: http://sproutdesigns.co.uk/clients/scroll

The problem seems to be that when I first slick it doesnt scroll, but jumps, and also doesn't seem to work every time. Is this because it is loading so much? or is there any way to make this any smoother and more reliable.

I ahve also looked into lazyload, but notice that this is no longer supported, is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a javascript error.

Message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Address:
telecomsadvisor.json

Comment: Hi, I have removed the error, but the same is still happening. the first few clicks don't scroll, and pages are slow to scroll. Any idea why?

Comment: I have now tested this in a few different browsers, and certainly getting this issue, can anyone help me pinpoint the problem: http://sproutdesigns.co.uk/clients/scroll

Comment: Hi, I have removed all reference to the twitter feed, so the error is not showing. But the issue is still there. First time a link is clicked it jumps, and then they start to scroll. Slower loading in other areas. Any ideas?

Comment: Clear your cache and try again. I don't see anything jumping.

Comment: Cleared Cache, and tried on a few computers. The first load, when I click about - it jumps rather than scrolling

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I have been working through the errors which were due to the Twitter feed enterpreting as json (not sure on a fix) and also that the hash in localscroll was causing an issue (documented problem). It's good to get a second view on this.